# Find distribution of Random Variable $X_N$ where $N$ is independent random variable, $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n P(N=j)=1$ & each $X_i~exp(\lambda_i)$

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence, cumulative-distribution-functions

**Question :** Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be independent random variables such that $X_i\sim\exp(\lambda_i)$ such that if $i\neq j$ then $\lambda_i\neq\lambda_j$.

Let $N$ be independent of these random variables such that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n P(N=j) = 1$

Find density, CDF, and hazard function of random variable $X_N$.

**My Approach**
Okay so firstly I'm not asking for help on CDF and hazard function, I'm wondering whether or not I'm able to simplify the equation I derived using total probability formula further.

I got
$$
P_{X_N}(t) = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j e^{-\lambda_j t}  P(N=j)
$$
Seems to me I can't go any further without knowing the actual distribution of $N$, however I want to make sure I can't go further just in case.

Comment: Please take a look at the MathJax formating now, so you are able to properly format your question next time. Also, the question probably reads: "Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be..."

Comment: Thanks Stefan for taking the time to format it.
Double checked the question but it does indeed read Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$

Meant to use a lowercase n for the highest $X_i$ though, not capital N. My bad